# Pandas resample to monthly, is giving incorrect output?

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying to `resample` data from `daily` to `monthly`

This is what I am doing

```
i = 'NSE/CHENNPETRO'
df = pdr.DataReader(i, 'quandl', start, end)
df_monthly = df['Close'].resample('M').ohlc()
```

`output:`

```
Date         open    high     low   close

2017-07-31  353.55  400.10  353.55  387.00
2017-08-31  414.30  448.35  378.05  448.35
2017-09-30  460.80  460.80  391.10  402.95
2017-10-31  405.70  468.80  403.10  468.80
2017-11-30  464.55  470.65  427.45  427.45
```

I checked it against the data for the `10`th month.

```
Open: 410
High: 478
Low: 400
Close: 468.8
```

I am not sure what I may be doing wrong. Very new to `pandas`

Comment: Do you know what `ohlc` is doing?

Comment: Getting the open, high, low, close values for the month from the underlying daily data, I assume. I am reading about it now.

Comment: You cannot up/downsample without performing some sort of operation. Mean? Max? Interpolation? Your end result is almost always going to be different from your input.

Comment: Ah..so, specify I want the max value in, 10th month, for the High column. And so on? The docs are not really clarifying it for me.

Comment: `resample('M').max()` for high, `resample('M').min()` for low.  For open & close you'd don't need to resample, just groupby and take first/last rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
df_monthly = df['Close'].resample('M').apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```